# How to install Delphi Chromium Embedded in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I'm trying to install Delphi Chromium in Delphi 2007, but there is not a .dpk file for this version in the 'packages' dir. There are packages for D7 and newer versions (XE, XE2), but not for 2007.

I tried to use the D7 package, but it returns me this error :

```
[DCC Error] chrome.dpr(6): F1026 File not found: 'cefgui.dcu'
```

The 'cefgui.pas' path is already on the library path.

I also can't open the XE package because it is on the newer project format and can't be opened by D2007.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Add the folder containing 'cefgui.pas' to the project search path.

Comment: Already did it, but the error remains.

Comment: There is no difference between the D7 version and what would be needed for a D2007 version except possibly version numbers in the RTL libraries. The error you're getting is because of a missing library path entry; that's the only reason for that error. If you're still getting it, you haven't added the proper path or you've added it in the wrong place.

Comment: I already added the correct path, the one the .pas files are stored in. There are no DCU files in this path although.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my download there is no `chrome.dpr` .

I do svn from [here delphichromiumembedded](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/)

`svn checkout http://delphichromiumembedded.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

I have Rad 2007 only on my Windows 2000 Computer
and I can only show you my installation process, with Delphi 7 package.

- Goto your `chromiumembedded\packages` there you run `chromium.bat`
- RAD Studio -> Open project -> DCEF_D7.dpk (not DCEF_D7.dproj)
- right click on `DCEF_D7.bpl` do a `compile` and a `install`

[image]

New palette `Chromium`

[image]

Test : `... chromiumembedded\demos\guiclient\guiclient.dpr` works

**Update:**

With the newest downloaded dcef3-0cc175e7a629.zip. I got the same error File not found: `cefgui.dcu`.
I got it to compile with the following steps.

- Download the four .dcu's from here [Chromiumembedded.zip](http://www.moskito-x.de/stack/Chromiumembedded.zip).
  They are from the older chromiumembedded.
- Put them into the src and packages folder.
- Compile
- Minimize the IDE
- Open `Notepad`
- Open cefgui.pas, ceflib.pas, cefvcl.pas, cefreg.pas in Notepad
- change the 4 files somewhat. (one, two letter is enough). Best, top in the comment. Save the files.
- Go back to the IDE
- Delphi inform you that files are changed outside the IDE : The question reload confirm with yes, the demand for renew the memory, also.
- Compile and you are done.
- if you want you can undo the changes at the four .pas files.

But beware: if you do a `clean` , then the four .dcu files will be deleted.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for such a detailed reply, but i'm using a newer version (DCEF3 from https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/), and i follow a similar procedure you showed but i always get this 'File not found: 'cefgui.dcu'. I did not tried the version you use, but i suppose it is an old version ?

Comment: @delphirules : downloaded `dcef3-0cc175e7a629.zip` the newest. (no `chrome.dpr` ) .Got the same error `File not found: 'cefgui.dcu'`. After some time I have got to compile it. If you are interested I can describe to you the steps.

Comment: please tell me the steps you did to install it, i really need to install it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I did exactly what you told, and i think i have some progress because now the error message changed ; now when i compile the dpk, i get this error : "[DCC Error] cefgui.pas(23): F1026 File not found: 'cef.inc'". But 'cef.inc' file is on the same folder as 'cefgui.pas' is. Any ideas ? Thank you very much !

Comment: After i close and open Delphi, now the error message changed : "[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'chromium.dcr'"

Comment: Well i don't know why, but i downloaded the files from the site again and did a fresh install, and it installed ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @delphirules : I am glad that we have solved the problem together :-)